# Using regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I am trying to use the following code to count the number of the whole word "the" in a file.  It keeps returning zero for the number of "the".  How would I make this work?

`totalthe=length(regexp(strcat(lines{:}),'\bthe\b'))`

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you might be using?

Comment: I have the lines of a file read into a cell.

Comment: Check  `\s` instead of '\b': `totalthe=length(regexp(strcat(lines{:}),'\sthe\s'))`

Comment: Other than using the proper MATLAB word boundary escape sequences (`\<` and `\>`), consider using [`regexpi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexpi.html) instead of `regexp` for case insensitive matching (you probably don't want to miss `The` at the beginning of sentences!)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, turns out I may have led you astray in a previous answer. Turns out the word boundaries for MATLAB are `\<` and `\>` (for the start and ending word boundaries respectively) instead of `\b`. I learnt something new today too.

Note that this is preferable to using `\s` (whitespace), as otherwise you might miss matches at the start and end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing all comments:

```
totalthe=length(regexpi(strvcat(lines{:}),'\<the\>'))
```

`strvcat` instead of `strcat` to prevent a leading `The` will not be stuck to a word at end of previous line.

Comment: Fails for `lines = {'In the'; 'hat'}`

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, based on the other answers, comments and some trial and error:

Suppose these are your lines:

```
lines = {'In the cell on the island'; 'there is the man.';'The end'}
```

Then this will count the occurance of 'the', case insensitive:

```
x = regexpi(lines,'\<the\>')
numel([x{:}])
```